# Can you use VAEs to produce deep word embeddings?

Tags: autoencoders, word-embeddings, word2vec, embeddings

There are many articles about applications of VAE such as image reconstruction, denoising, data compression / augmentation. However, I have not seen an example of embeddings for high dimensional data such as words.

Are there some papers about the use of VAE as embedding constructers ?

If there are, how do these deep embeddings compare with shallow technics such as Word2vec and other Skip-gram / Bag-of-words?

Comment: Interesting question - with a quick google search I found this - https://ijdykeman.github.io/ml/2017/05/12/vae-definition-generator.html I am not very sure how it compares with word2vec or bag-of-words. But I will update the answers if I find anything.

Comment: will have a look, seems interesting